# How to build and package custom spring-boot starter without deploy the starter to a remote maven repo

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I have two questions. one regarding debugging and editing an exist`spring-boot` starter. The second question is about building `a new custom stater`

### Debugging and editing an exist `spring-boot` starter

I want to be able to do some changes in `spring-boot-devtools`. In order to do so I cloned the repo. Imported the `spring-boot-devtools` folder as a module to my project in `Intellij`. In order to make `Intellij` use my own source instead of `maven repo` I removed from my `pom.xml` the dependency for `spring-boot-devtools`. Instead, I set the **local** `spring-boot-devtools` `module`  as dependency for my own project. (Intellij - project settings-module dependencies and add the  local `spring-boot-devtools` module as dependency)

This has an issue of resolving some `test` utils. But besides that I can run my own project with the local `spring-boot-devtools` module and for this purpose it works ok.

But since `spring-boot-devtools` is no longer part of the pom I cannot `package` my project with the `devtools`... 
And here is my first question: What is the best practice in order to development on exist `spring-boot` starter and make sure I 'll be able to include it the the packaged jar?

### Building custom `spring-boot` starter

I'm learning how to build a custom `spring-boot` starter. I want use the starter in my own project. What is best practice for managing the structure of the `starter` it self, and how do I connect it to my own project in a way it will be easy to update, debug and package all things together

Thanks,
Oak

Answer (score 0):

Change the Group & Artifact ID for `spring-boot-devtools` and then build this package using

`mvn clean install`

Then add this dependency to you pom using the new Group & Artifact ID

**NOTE**: This only works locally since you aren't using a remote artifact repository.

For more specific instructions on building custom spring boot starters see these resources:

- [Spring Boot Documentation - Custom Starters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-custom-starter)
- [Sample Project -GitHub](https://github.com/snicoll-demos/spring-boot-master-auto-configuration)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the information but If I do that  I need to "mvn install" on module `spring-boot-devtools` everytime I update the code, right? I'm looking for a solution that allows single build for both project. I imagine  something like npm has(http://justjs.com/posts/npm-link-developing-your-own-npm-modules-without-tears)

Comment: @oak Why not make it a multi-module maven project?  You can build all modules with a single command from the root directory: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html

Comment: this seems like a better solution than the above .. :)